# R: Multiple conditions with non existing columns

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I am using a program, which provides an excel table as a research result. 
There are a lot of columns, like `Title 1`, `Title 2` so on.

Sometimes, some of those columns might be absent - like there will be no `Title 2` at all.

I want to create code, which will account for tables that might be missing. 
Basically to 1 check which columns exist in the table, and then filter available data.

The problem is, if while filter, there is a non-existing column - code stops with an error, and I need it to just move on to the next calculation.

I came up with a long solution:

```
if( "Title 2"%in% (colnames(Meta_Data))&"Meta Description 2"%in%(colnames(Meta_Data))&"H1-2"%in%(colnames(Meta_Data)))

  {Correct <- Meta_Data %>%  
      filter(  `Title 1 Length` > 60 | `Title 1 Length` < 50 
            |  `Title 2 Length` > 60 | `Title 2 Length` < 50
            |  `Meta Description 1 Length`> 300 | `Meta Description 1` < 50
            |  `Meta Description 2 Length`> 300 | `Meta Description 2` < 50
            |  `H1-1`>70   | `H1-1` < 20
            |  `H1-2` > 70 | `H1-2` < 20
            |  `H2-1`>70   | `H2-1` < 20
            |  `H2-2` > 70 | `H2-2` < 20
            )
} else if("Meta Description 2"%in%(colnames(Meta_Data)) & "H1-2"%in%(colnames(Meta_Data)))
  {Correct <- Meta_Data %>%  
      filter   (  `Title 1 Length` > 60 | `Title 1 Length` < 50 
               |  `Meta Description 1 Length`> 300 | `Meta Description 1` < 50
               |  `Meta Description 2 Length`> 300 | `Meta Description 2` < 50
               |  `H1-1`>70   | `H1-1` < 20
               |  `H1-2` > 70 | `H1-2` < 20
               |  `H2-1`>70   | `H2-1` < 20
               |  `H2-2` > 70 | `H2-2` < 20
      )

} else if ("Title 2" %in% (colnames(Meta_Data)) &"H1-2"%in% (colnames(Meta_Data)))
  {Correct <- Meta_Data %>%  
    filter   (  `Title 1 Length` > 60 | `Title 1 Length` < 50 
             |  `Title 2 Length` > 60 | `Title 2 Length` < 50
             |  `Meta Description 1 Length`> 300 | `Meta Description 1` < 50
             |  `H1-1`>70   | `H1-1` < 20
             |  `H1-2` > 70 | `H1-2` < 20
             |  `H2-1`>70   | `H2-1` < 20
             |  `H2-2` > 70 | `H2-2` < 20
    )

} else if("Title 2"%in%(colnames(Meta_Data))&"Meta Description 2"%in%(colnames(Meta_Data)))
  {Correct <- Meta_Data %>%  
    filter   (  `Title 1 Length` > 60 | `Title 1 Length` < 50 
             |  `Title 2 Length` > 60 | `Title 2 Length` < 50
             |  `Meta Description 1 Length`> 300 | `Meta Description 1` < 50
             |  `Meta Description 2 Length`> 300 | `Meta Description 2` < 50
             |  `H1-1`>70   | `H1-1` < 20
             |  `H2-1`>70   | `H2-1` < 20
             |  `H2-2` > 70 | `H2-2` < 20
    )

} else if ("H1-2"%in%(colnames(Meta_Data)))
  { Correct <- Meta_Data %>%  
    filter(  `Title 1 Length` > 60 | `Title 1 Length` < 50 
             |  `Meta Description 1 Length`> 300 | `Meta Description 1` < 50
             |  `H1-1`>70   | `H1-1` < 20
             |  `H1-2` > 70 | `H1-2` < 20
             |  `H2-1`>70   | `H2-1` < 20
             |  `H2-2` > 70 | `H2-2` < 20
    )

} else if ("Meta Description 2"%in%(colnames(Meta_Data)))
  {Correct <- Meta_Data %>%  
    filter(  `Title 1 Length` > 60 | `Title 1 Length` < 50 
             |  `Meta Description 1 Length`> 300 | `Meta Description 1` < 50
             |  `Meta Description 2 Length`> 300 | `Meta Description 2` < 50
             |  `H1-1`>70   | `H1-1` < 20
             |  `H2-1`>70   | `H2-1` < 20
             |  `H2-2` > 70 | `H2-2` < 20
    )

} else if ("Title 2"%in%(colnames(Meta_Data)))
  {Correct <- Meta_Data %>%  
    filter(  `Title 1 Length` > 60 | `Title 1 Length` < 50 
             |  `Title 2 Length` > 60 | `Title 2 Length` < 50
             |  `Meta Description 1 Length`> 300 | `Meta Description 1` < 50
             |  `H1-1`>70   | `H1-1` < 20
             |  `H2-1`>70   | `H2-1` < 20
             |  `H2-2` > 70 | `H2-2` < 20
    )
} else 
  {Correct <- Meta_Data %>%
    filter (`Title 1 Length` > 60 | `Title 1 Length` < 50 
            |  `Meta Description 1 Length`> 300 | `Meta Description 1` < 50
            |  `H1-1`>70   | `H1-1` < 20
            |  `H2-1`>70   | `H2-1` < 20
            |  `H2-2` > 70 | `H2-2` < 20

    )

}
```

This takes into account `Title 2`| `Meta Description 2` | `H1-2`

However, it appears I should also account for `H2-2` and this will add a lot more iterations/lines of code.

(NOTE: if the column `Title 2` exists, then `Title 2 Length` exists as well, this works with other columns too).

I want to understand, if there is simpler solution (there should be) as itll be a nightmare if there are more than 5 conditions (columns) which might or migt not exist.
(Unfortunately, I dont have good math or coding background)

Comment: are the name of columns consistent even if they don't exist? Meaning does `Title 2` for two different imported sheets relate?

Comment: If I got you correct, then the Yes, they are. `Title 2` will appear on the same spot (as any other column, if it is found, during a search by a program. 
The problem is, that you cannot be 100% sure that all "2" ( like `Title 2`, `Meta 2`, `H1-2` will or will not be, per each research. (guess this is the main challenge).

Comment: Then if you have several dfs, not all having all the columns that appear across all the dfs, have you tried to stack the dfs on top of each other with `bind_rows` from `dplyr`? This is more forgiving than `rbind` in that it'll just introduce `NA`s where no column exists in that given df.

Comment: This is indeed a good idea. Though I need to know if there is indeed anything with "2" in its name. 
This makes me think of another approach to analysing this data.

Yet, this deviates from my original idea, to have everything filtered column by column, to see exactly, which columns are in the set, and the data for each separately.
Though if I `bind_column`, I will have a duplicate in a URL column (probably should have mentioned whole data set for analysis), and then I can define where is any "2" for columns. 
Thank you. (yet want to see, maybe there are other solutions this is close

Comment: why can't you do that conditionally with `if_else` and `grepl`? if the conditions are met (or not) then `bind_rows`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can build a data.frame as a reference for the columns and knowing which columns you have available and then just filter.

In the end it's less code and easier to update if you have a new column or new column/filter you want to add to your Excel output.

Let me show my approach

1. First we have to create the data frame with one column containing column names and the other one the code that will go inside filter

```
# in col_names write every column name that can be filtered
# and in ch_filter the filter command you want to apply to your Meta_Data
df <- data.frame(col_names = c('Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Meta Description 2', 'H1-2' ),
                 ch_filter = c('`Title 1` > 60', '`Title 2` < 50', '`Meta Description 2` < 50',
                               '`H1-2` > 20 | `H1-2` < 50' ))
```

2. So now you have a data frame which you can filter and you can verify if you have a certain column

```
# get column names of your data
vector_names <- names(Meta_Data)

# filter your data.frame built in step 1
filter_options <- filter(df, col_names %in% vector_names)
```

3. Finally you can do your filter now you know the columns you have in your data_frame. We have to use the `filter_()` function, so you can paste the text in the `ch_filter` column.

```
# this will collapse all the filter instructions separated by a pipe " | "
Correct <- Meta_Data %>%
 filter(.dots = paste(filter_options$ch_filter, collapse = ' | '))
```

Hope this helps and will make your code more cleaner and easily to modify if you have a new column

Comment: Thank you for the option!

I do understand that knowing exactly, which columns are in the dataset is the easiest way (and at some point faster) but the aim for the whole thing is to write a code, which can sort of adjust to changing dataset.

I think important part I forgot to mentioned:

Comment: I am still thinking if there is a way to say (with the code) 

`filter( `Title 1`, **`Title 2` **, `Meta Description 1`)`
**If there is no title 2 - drop it and proceed to next iteration**

I used `one_of` function, to gather columns from the main set:

`df <- one_of("Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3")`
 so if there is no "Title 2" or "Title 3" it just adds what exists and send warning, that there is something missing, but it doesnt stop calculation.